# How to simulate an EOF?

Tags: c, eof, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am currently reading K&R's book and typing in the examples from the first section, and there are a couple of examples such as this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    //do something
}
```

I am testing these examples on a Windows box and thus running the compiled exe files from the `cmd` prompt.

To test the example above, how do I simulate an `EOF`?  That is, basically how can I make the loop stop when testing the example from the command prompt?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To enter an EOF, use:

1. ^Z  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) in Windows
2. ^D on Unix-like systems

Comment: Some useful addition: If you are on a line that's not empty, you will have to double press ^D: Pressing it one time will flush that line, pressing it another time will send EOF. If you are on an empty line, one ^D is enough.

Comment: That's the <kbd> HTML element.

Comment: In Windows, entering ^Z only produces EOF if done at the start of a line.

Answer (score 22):

Refer [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

```
Windows: Ctrl+Z
Unix :Ctrl+D
```

Answer (score 2):

First, press: Ctrl^X, next: Ctrl^D

Answer (score 1):

You can also simulate EOF by explicitly giving int variable a value of -1.

Check out this code for more clarity:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {    
    // char ch=getchar()
    // int ch=-1;

    if(ch==EOF) { printf("\nEOF: %d",EOF); }
    if((ch!=EOF)==0) { printf("\nit is equal to 0"); }
    if((ch!=EOF)==1) { printf("\nit is equal to 1"); }
    else { printf("\n it is equal to other value"); }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it could be a different value than -1. -1 is only a convention (or the value for EOF under a few OSes)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after pressing *Ctrl+d* program stopped and returned 0.
If you use **Clion** press *Ctrl+Shift+a* than type Registry press enter and make sure **run.processes.with.pty.** is unchecked.
After that compile program again and then you can type in input but **don't press *Ctrl+d* on the same line as input** it will return 0 or Error.