# How to trigger EOF (End-Of-File) in C Programming Language in Netbeans IDE

Tags: c, netbeans, eof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C : How to simulate an EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof)

I am currently trying to get use to C programming language. I have learnt java, so I am a bit familiar with the code style and all, but obviously there are differences.

This is the code that I currently have. It is from textbook, so I am assuming there is nothing wrong with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long numberOfCharacter;

    numberOfCharacter = 0;

    while(getchar() != EOF)
    {
        ++numberOfCharacter;
    }

    printf("%1d\n", numberOfCharacter);
}
```

I think that I have to trigger EOF in order to get the output that I want. I saw some other posts and they said to press Ctrl+Z to trigger the EOF, and I've tried but it doesn't work. I am assuming because it is Netbeans. So, the question is how do you trigger EOF in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Linux system, try CTRL-D instead of CTRL-Z.