# Ctrl + C handler working on some hosts and not on other hosts

Tags: c, signals

I have written following CTRL+C handler but the problem is its working fine on some hosts but not working on other hosts. Can anyone please help me out.

```
void signalhandler( int num)
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalhandler);
}
```

and

EDIT:

```
int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, signalhandler);
  /*------------------*/
}
```

---

[update from comment]

I mean the program does not terminate with CTRL + C while running on some hosts but the same program is getting terminated while running on some other hosts.

Comment: Define working fine and not working please ?

Comment: I mean the program does not terminate with CTRL + C while running on some hosts but the same program is getting terminated while running on some other hosts.

Comment: Does you "*real*" code test the outcome of the call to `signal()` against `SIG_ERR`. I might very fail.

Comment: Also which platforms do those "*hosts*" you use represent? Using `signal()` to install signal handlers is highly unportable.

Comment: all the hosts are Redhat with same version still the problem is arising

Comment: i am not comparing it with SIG_ERR

Answer (score -1):

When you say

> "working fine on some hosts but not working on other hosts"

I assume you are referring host to other platform like Redhat, Solaris etc. From my experience, some old server use `ctrl + D` or `ctrl + Z` as interrupt signal. This is answered based on experience. Might or might not be your case.

If you need a reference to learn about signal handling in C, I suggest you to read [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html) page first. Then you can try and read more on [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_21.html) page. Might be or might not be a solution on your case. But worth reading to increase knowledge about signal.

Comment: Ctrl-D and Ctrl-Z are the keystrokes to feed a reading stream with an EOF. The first is used by IXish systems the latter by Windows. Using Ctrl-C to generate a SIGINT is a completely different story.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining that. Can you share a link for that info?

Comment: On the usage of Ctrl-D/Ctrl-Z you might like to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1118957/694576

Comment: If u have the answer will you please share it with me