# How to quit from input() function after call codecs.getreader for stdin?

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, console

I try to read from windows console utf-8 letters.

I have the code follows:

```
import codecs
sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print 'query=',
    query = sys.stdin.readline()
    print query
```

But there is a strange thing:

After pressing the enter button the execution of the `stdin.readline()` or `raw_input()` or `input()` functions will not stop.

What do I do wrong? Or how to send `eof()` to stop input from console in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Mac, hitting ^D (Ctrl-D) twice does the trick. Not sure if this will work across systems, but give it a shot.

Comment: I found next
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof#comment53315664_1118966
In Windows my code will not work. It so sad.