# How to break from the scanner.scan() for-loop?

Tags: go

When I use "bufio" package, the standard code is just like:

```
input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for input.Scan() {
    // xxxxx
}
```

When I run the program, the for-loop can't stop whatever I input. I have tried newline, space, ctrl-d, ctrl-z. According to the document, a blank newline should be able to stop the program.

The program is running under Windows 7 CMD environment, or mingw-bash.

Thanks.

Comment: the scan() stops either by reaching the end of the input or an error

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan

Comment: Agree with @icza it's a duplicate. By the way just curious according to what document it is supposed to stop for a blank newline?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok I misunderstand the document. I've got the answer from the duplicate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may input some specific string as a signal to stop the loop. In the below example, whenever "quit" is entered, the loop breaks.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for input.Scan() {
        indata := input.Text()
        if indata == "quit" {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can simulate `EOF` in terminal. On **Linux** is `CTRL + D`, on **Windows** `CTRL + Z`: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof)