# stop codeblock compiler and return values

Tags: c++, cmd

I am using codeblock for c++ programming.
I have an issue.

How I can stop this function in codeblock and return values

```
vector<double>vec;
double x;

while(cin>>x)
{
    vec.push_back(x);
}
```

I tried `Ctrl + c` but it stops entire run block

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Z` do the trick?

Comment: Do you need infinite numbers through standar input?

Comment: Type in some non-numeric characters...

Comment: See this [answer: ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof)

Comment: @ jsheeran yeah kdude. it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system you can stop the reading from standard input using either CTRL-Z (Windows OS) or CTRL-D (*nix like OS).

That will send a EOF character to `cin`.

To use `cin` afterwards for reading further input you need to call

```
cin.clear();
```

That will reset the `eof` flag.

---

<sub>A side note: CTRL-C doesn't *stop the compiler* but the running executable from the terminal used.</sub>