# Character count in C won't return any value after input of a character

Tags: c

My code does not return any value. Can anyone help me explain why it does not work?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Seems to work https://ideone.com/Qib4xU

Comment: PS: `"%1d\n"` should be `"%d\n"`

Comment: I am using Mac OS. I am expecting it to return number of character in an input character.

Comment: For example, if I type a character C, then it should return 2.

Comment: Have you tried my change above

Comment: @BillCao Number of characters in an input character? Do you mean number of characters in input string?

Comment: Type `C` and return `2`?

Comment: @theausome The code does give that output. `nc`'s value is incremented twice. Once for `2` and the other for typing enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to input `EOF` to get out of the loop.

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Linux  : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

See [C : How to simulate an EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof)

Only after `getchar()` returns `EOF` will the value of `nc` be printed.

And `%1d` is effectively same as `%d` as a number has at least one digit.

If you do `%10d` or something the number would be printed occupying the space that would've been occupied by a 10 digit number. Default alignment is right.
You can make it left aligned with `%-10d`

Comment: I used Ctrl + Z in my Mac OS terminal console and it seems it only helped to terminate the while loop but it did not return any count value.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. I inputed "okay"\n "y", it returns 6D, what does it mean?

Comment: If I just input "y", then it will return 1D. Does the program just count the the total of characters in an input string plus all the n\?

Comment: @BillCao Is it not what you wanted to do?

Comment: @BillCao: Using control-Z on a Unix box suspends the process; it does not terminate the process.  It is still running, but in suspended animation until you type a magic incantation at the shell (`fg %1`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the input when you run the code. You have to type in the console after compilation is done. Right now it's not getting any input character to count.

The same code works for me. You can check the below ideone screenshot where same code is returning the correct output . 
[image]