# What will be output of this code ?How EOF terminate in terminal?

Tags: c

I am not able to print the count c in this c code.

I have tried in a terminal with many lines.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

    long c=0;
    while(getchar()!=EOF)
        ++c;
    printf("%ld\n",c);
}
```

expected result should be characters we provide.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler issue a warning about using `long c` uninitialized?

Comment: Local (automatic) variables are not initialized. Their values are *indeterminate*. Any descent text-book or tutorial or teacher should have taught you that.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`. And for future reference, please indicate in your question what output you got. I expect your program would have printed some arbitrary integer value. (It "worked" for me, apparently because `c` just happened to have the initial value zero.)

Comment: My program did not give me compile error.It just not complete in terminal.I want to know  about EOF .

Comment: I suspect that, once you fix the issues pointed out in the comments, your question will be answered by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/c-how-to-simulate-an-eof

Answer (score 2):

Your program exposes undefined behaviour, since `c` is not initialized.
Actually every answer predicting the result of `c` is wrong, even if one said "it's garbage". Your variable `c` is a local variable with automatic storage duration, so it does not get initialized per se; In expression `++c`, your variable is an lvalue as it designates an object. See what the standard says concerning lvalues and non-initialized (cf., for example [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1) online C11 standard draft):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> 1...
>
> 2... If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never
>   had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), **the behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

To signal `EOF` in a terminal you type a special key, depending on the operating system you use. Examples:

- On Windows (`cmd`) it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.
- On Linux it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

You need to type this at the beginning of a line.