# Program accepting input from stdin but not from terminal

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my program

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
public:
    Student(string input)
    {
        name = input;
    }
    Student()
    {
        name = "Unknown";
    }
    void get_name()
    {
        char c;
      
    while (getline(cin, name))
    { 
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {

        c = name.at(i);         

        if (! ( ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) || c==' ' || c=='\n') ) {

             name = "Unknown";
        }
     }
 }

    }
    void print_name()
    {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
        Student name;
        name.get_name();
        name.print_name();
    return 0;
}
```

It is accepting input from stdin & working properly but not from the terminal in any way.
I can't understand this behavior of the program.

Terminal input not working

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyLRV.jpg

STDIN input

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj6fH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```cpp
while (getline(cin, name))
```

Into

```cpp
if (getline(cin, name))
```

May works as you expected. You haven't broken out the loop, so it's always waiting for console input.

Or you can send an `EOF` in the console, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118957/how-to-simulate-an-eof).

Full program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
  string name;

 public:
  Student(string input) { name = input; }
  Student() { name = "Unknown"; }
  void get_name() {
    char c;

    if (getline(cin, name)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        c = name.at(i);

        if (!((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || c == ' ' ||
              c == '\n')) {
          name = "Unknown";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  void print_name() { cout << name << endl; }
};

int main() {
  Student name;
  name.get_name();
  name.print_name();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void get_name()
{
    char c;
    getline(cin, name);

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {

        c = name.at(i);

        if (!((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || c == ' ' || c == '\n'))
        {

            name = "Unknown";
        }
    }
    
}
```

No need for while loop there. If you put while there then it will take input forever. You can use a loop and try breaking it but it won't be efficient.